# StackPanel in ScrollViewer WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar

I've got a problem with extremly strange behaviour of ScrollViewer's ScrollBar.

Here is my code:

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Height="40"/>
            <Button Height="40"/>
            <Button Height="40"/>
            <Button Height="40"/>
            <Button Height="40"/>
            <Button Height="40"/>
            <Button Height="40"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Yellow"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Green"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The problem is in those StackPanels inside StackPanel. If there's only one main StackPanel without StackPanels inside it, it acts ok.

I've tried using ScrollViewer inside main StackPanel for each of it's childrens. The other problem in that solution is that I don't want to have fixed height of StackPanels.

**@EDIT:**
The problem is that ScrollBar doesn't shift smoothly and it prevents showing all the content. Sorry for lack of informations.

Comment: What doesnt work here? what do you mean by _it acts ok_? If I understand your problem correctly, remove `CanContentScroll=True` and try.

Comment: Dude, you need to explain what your problem actually is, rather than just saying 'I have a problem'. Either way, I'm guessing that your problem relates to the fact that a `StackPanel` won't resize its contents... just use a `Grid` instead... a `StackPanel` is all but useless for *most* occasions.

Comment: I didn't want to use Grid because of necessity of manipulations with margins.

Comment: As mentioned it's not entirely clear what the problem is, if it's to do with smooth scrollbar scrolling, this might be what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013841/wpf-datagrid-rowdetail-is-cut-off/19014608#19014608 but it may be completely unrelated.

Comment: @Doro did you try removing `CanContentScroll=True` ?

Comment: Ok, I will make my comment an answer, you could then accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that strange behaviour because you set `CanContentScroll` to True on `ScrollViewer`. That means, the ScorllViewer is treating each `StackPanel` as a single content element and scrolling by height of each `StackPanel` instead of height of each `Button` within the child `StackPanel`s.

To get rid of that strange behavior, change your code to:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Height="40"/>
            <Button Height="40"/>
            <Button Height="40"/>
            <Button Height="40"/>
            <Button Height="40"/>
            <Button Height="40"/>
            <Button Height="40"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Yellow"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
            <Button Height="40" Background="Green"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You "need" add your StackPanels to ItemsControl  collection:

```
 <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
      <ItemsControl >
           <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button Height="40"/>
                    <Button Height="40"/>
                    <Button Height="40"/>
                    <Button Height="40"/>
                    <Button Height="40"/>
                    <Button Height="40"/>
                    <Button Height="40"/>
                    <Button Height="40" Background="Yellow"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel>
                    <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
                    <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
                    <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
                    <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
                    <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
                    <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
                    <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
                    <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
                    <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
                    <Button Height="40" Background="Red"/>
                    <Button Height="40" Background="Green"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
       </ItemsControl >
   </ScrollViewer>
```